# Why do my versions of Java differ?

Tags: macos, homebrew, java

If I `brew --config`, I see

```
#...
Java: 1.8.0_60
```

which is what my my OS X Java Control Panel reported until I recently updated. Now the control panel reports the new version

> Java 8 Update 65

but `brew --config` continues to report the old one.

Why do these two versions of Java differ? I haven't explicitly installed a different Java with Homebrew, and had always thought that Homebrew was reporting the version of he one Java I'm aware of: the one I installed when Java notified be of an update.

Comment: How exactly did you update Java i.e. exact URLs etc

Comment: Using the Java Updater: it notified me of the update and I accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

Accoding to the [Java 8 JRE documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jre.html#A1098497)

> Installing a JRE from Oracle will not update java -version symlinks or add java to your path. To be able to do this, you need to install the JDK.

To solve this problem, you have to install the [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

One easy way to do it is with [Homebrew-Cask](https://caskroom.github.io/) :

```
brew cask install java
```

If you already installed a previous java version via Homebrew Cask :

```
brew cask reinstall java
```